# How to get the previous record in snowflake

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the previous record of a `pgft.name` and `pj.name` in the below query, since it should return older data which may not be result set, LAG function cannot be used.

I am looking for 2 new columns `previous_pgft.name` and `previous_pj.name` kindly help

```
SELECT paaf.person_id,paaf.effective_start_date
,papf.person_number
,pgft.name
,pj.name
FROM 

per_all_assignments_f paaf

LEFT JOIN per_all_people_f_VW papf ON papf.person_id=paaf.person_id 
    AND CAST(paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) BETWEEN CAST(papf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) AND CAST(papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE AS date)                                               
LEFT JOIN PER_GRADES_F_VL_VW pgft ON pgft.grade_id=paaf.grade_id
    AND CAST(paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) BETWEEN CAST(pgft.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) AND CAST(pgft.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE AS date)
LEFT JOIN PER_JOBS_F_VL_VW pj ON pj.job_id=paaf.job_id
    AND CAST(paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) BETWEEN CAST(pj.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) AND CAST(pj.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE AS date)
  
WHERE paaf.effective_start_date between '2020-01-01' AND '2023-06-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code solved the issue and also running faster.

```
 SELECT paaf.person_id,paaf.effective_start_date
,papf.person_number
,pgft.name
,pj.name
,prev_pgft.name
,prev_pj.name

FROM 

per_all_assignments_f paaf

LEFT JOIN per_all_people_f_VW papf ON papf.person_id=paaf.person_id 
    AND CAST(paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) BETWEEN CAST(papf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) AND CAST(papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE AS date)                                               
LEFT JOIN PER_GRADES_F_VL_VW pgft ON pgft.grade_id=paaf.grade_id
    AND CAST(paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) BETWEEN CAST(pgft.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) AND CAST(pgft.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE AS date)
LEFT JOIN PER_JOBS_F_VL_VW pj ON pj.job_id=paaf.job_id
    AND CAST(paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) BETWEEN CAST(pj.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS date) AND CAST(pj.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE AS date)
  
LEFT JOIN per_all_assignments_f_VW2 prev_asg ON prev_asg.person_id = paaf.person_id
    AND prev_asg.assignment_id =  paaf.assignment_id
    AND prev_asg.assignment_type = 'E'
    AND prev_asg.primary_flag='Y'
    AND CAST(paaf.effective_start_date AS date)-1 BETWEEN CAST(prev_asg.effective_start_date AS date) AND  CAST(prev_asg.effective_end_date AS date)

LEFT JOIN per_grades_f_vl_VW prev_pgft ON prev_pgft.grade_id = prev_asg.grade_id
    AND CAST(prev_asg.effective_start_date AS date) BETWEEN CAST(prev_pgft.effective_start_date AS date) AND  CAST(prev_pgft.effective_end_date AS date)

LEFT JOIN per_jobs_f_vl prev_pj ON prev_pj.job_id = prev_asg.job_id
    AND CAST(prev_asg.effective_start_date AS date) BETWEEN CAST(prev_pj.effective_start_date AS date) AND  CAST(prev_pj.effective_end_date AS date)

WHERE paaf.effective_start_date between '2020-01-01' AND '2023-06-31'
```